# Why is using static methods not good for unit-testing?

Tags: java, unit-testing

I heard that creating object with static methods is not good for unit-testing. For instance, we have the following hierarchy:

```
public abstract class Base{

    public static Base createConcrete(){
        return new Concrete();
    }

    public static Base createSuperConcrete(){
        return new SuperConcrete();
    }
}

public class Concrete extends Base { }

public class SuperConcrete extends Base { }
```

It's better use instance FactoryMethod instead. Why does using `static` methods cause too much pain in unit tests? Couldn't someone give an example?

Comment: In your example, it doesn't matter so much that the methods are `static`, because your clients will already be tied to the method names which name the actual class being instantiated.

Comment: @quamrana So in what example it does matter?

Comment: Have you googled first? Wasn't [this](http://misko.hevery.com/2008/12/15/static-methods-are-death-to-testability/) or [this](http://www.jramoyo.com/2013/03/static-methods-and-unit-testing.html) helpful?

Comment: `static` methods cannot be overridden, so a unit test cannot supply different mock objects for different tests.

Answer (score 1):

The main drawback of your approach is that there's no way to make the clients of your `Base` class work with anything other than `Concrete` and `SuperConcrete`.

Think of the following example: both `Concrete` and `SuperConcrete` require some expensive resources to initialize (database connections or whatever).

The classes that use the `Base` class will trigger all that heavy-lifting on calling `Base.createConcrete()` -- so you can only have integration tests for that reason.

On the other hand, if `create*Concrete` were instance methods, you could provide your clients with a mocked/dummy implementation of `Base` that creates lightweight "concrete" instances, just enough for running your test cases. You'll be able to use frameworks like Mockito or just create dummy implementations by hand.

Mocking static methods is only possible with really intrusive tools like `PowerMock` (if possible at all) and thus makes your test code unnecessarily complex.